# Empty Response with 'UrlFetchApp.fetch' when Connecting to LinkedIn API AND limited API Calls

Tags: google-apps-script, linkedin-api, looker-studio

we would like to create our own app using LinkedIn for Developers in order to develop a connector (Google Apps Script) for an internally used dashboard for Google Looker Studio.

We are encountering the following issues:

1. Currently, we are working and testing the LinkedIn API calls with a limit of only 10 requests per day - the limit seems to be on the LinkedIn side. How can we increase the limits on API calls for the LinkedinAPI?
2. When I try to connect to the API using 'UrlFetchApp.fetch,' I only receive {} - an empty object. However, when using the same request (including the headers described in the documentation) in Postman, I get the expected JSON object with data. What could be the reason for this?

These are the Calls that we want to perform:

- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:<companyId>`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/networkSizes/urn:li:organization:<companyId>?edgeType=CompanyFollowedByMember`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn:li:organization:<companyId>`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationPageStatistics?q=organization&organization=urn:li:organization:<companyId>`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/seniorities/<id>?locale.language=de&locale.country=DE`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/industries/<id>`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/functions/<id>?locale=de_DE`
- `https://api.linkedin.com/rest/geo/<id>`

This is our currently used code example:

```js
/**
 * @param url The needed url
 * @returns In future parse the response from JSON (Sinc data come in)
 */
function doRequest(url) {
  var oAuthService = getOAuthService();
  var optionsGet = {
    'method': 'get',
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oAuthService.getAccessToken(),
      'Linkedin-Version': '202304',
    }
  };
  console.log('URL\n', url);
  console.log('options GET:\n', optionsGet);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, optionsGet);
  console.log('### RESP\n', JSON.stringify(response));
  console.log('Header\n', response.getAllHeaders());

  return response;
}
```

Please let me know if you need any further information or assistance.